# For $f \in l_1^*$ to be true

Tags: functional-analysis

Do we have to check whether $f$ is linear and bounded ? As in $f \in L(X,Y)$ ?

To show that $f \in L(X,Y)$, it is enough to prove that $f$ is linear and for boundedness that

$\exists M > 0$ such that $||f(x)|| \leq M||x||$, where $x \in X$ and $ f(x) \in Y$

Does the same apply for dual space?

Comment: Hint: This sounds like you're confused about what a _definition_ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, for $f$ being in $(l^1)^{*}$ you have to show the following:

- $f$ is linear.
- $f$ is bounded i.e., $|f(x)| \leq \|x\|_1$